# Why correlated subquery result cannot be used in outer query?

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

Why correlated subquery result cannot be used in outer query?

In below query I want to access the count in the inner corrleated query in outer query. But it is giving error.

**What am I doing wrong?**

referenct - http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations#Looking_at_the_id_field.

Question- 14 (Obtain a list in alphabetical order of actors who've had at least 30 starring roles.)

```
select distinct a.name  , t.count
from actor a 
join casting c 
on (a.id= c.actorid) 
where 25< (select count(movieid) as count 
    from casting c1 
    where c1.actorid= a.id) as t
order by a.name
```

Below query works fine.

```
select distinct a.name, (select count(movieid) as count 
    from casting c1 
    where c1.actorid= a.id)
from   actor a 
join casting c 
on (a.id= c.actorid)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e7be/8

Comment: You know you can do this without a subquery right? Also, what error do you get? I can't reproduce the issue here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e7be/1

Comment: Subquery referred in `WHERE` clause, loses scope at outer `SELECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` is a column in the subquery, but it is not part of the outer join. Therefore, it is not visible outside the subquery itself.

An easier way to tackle this would be by computing the count within your join itself, like so:

```
select a.name, count(movieid)
from
actor a 
join casting c
on a.id = c.actorid
group by a.name, a.id
having count(movieid) > 3
order by a.name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d438a/5)

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking two things. one for starring roles, two for at least 30 times. You can use WHERE to solve the first one, then group the result to count. Finally use HAVING to filter the second question.

You can use COUNT function in HAVING statement.

```
SELECT actor.name
 FROM actor JOIN casting ON actor.id = casting.actorid
 WHERE ord = 1
 GROUP BY actor.name
 HAVING COUNT(actor.name) >= 30
 ORDER BY actor.name
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT`name `FROM`  casting `JOIN` actor on actor.id=casting.actorid 
`WHERE` ord=1 `GROUP BY` name 
`HAVING COUNT`(movieid)>=30

Comment: Please explain why and how this solved the issue, don't just post code. Also, format it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name
FROM actor
JOIN casting ON (id = actorid AND (SELECT COUNT(ord) FROM casting 
WHERE actorid = actor.id AND ord=1)>=30)
GROUP BY name

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked fine:

```
select actor.name
from actor
join casting on casting.actorid=actor.id
join movie on casting.movieid=movie.id
where casting.ord=1
group by actor.name
having count(actor.name) > 29
order by actor.name
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.